# How to save video stream from webcam as an image instead of an flv video file using flash?

Tags: flash, flash-media-server

This will create an flv video file on flash media server:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
ns.publish("yourCamera", "record");
ns.attachVideo(Camera.get());
```

How can I generate an image for the current video frame every 2 seconds?

Comment: Do you want just a snapshot or change the time elapsed between recorded frames ?

Comment: @phwd, do you have a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a timelapse (take a photo ever so often) you want to attach the Video to a camera, something like

```
video.attachCamera(Camera.getCamera());
```

Then draw the video as BitmapData on a `TimerEvent` firing listening to a `Timer` instance you define, and push it into an array

```
bmpData.draw(video);
arr.push(bmpData);
```

From here you can encode the bitmap data to a ByteArray of your choice of encoding (JPG,BMP)